# Passing result from one class to another

Tags: react-native

please dont roast me directly, i'm pretty new to react-native but hopefully someone is able to help me and give me a better understanding.

I've got two classes, "SelectImage" which opens up the ImagePicker and let the user select a photo from it's library and the main class which renders the Page "ShowContent".
In the rendered page a onPress event calls the function "SelectImage_func" which opens the imagepicker via the "SelectImage" class, that is working so far and so good and console.log(...) shows me the uri of the selected image.

But i want that URI now to be available in the "ShowContent" class, maybe as the state.cover value, can i achieve that some how or can someone tell me the way to do it please?

Thank you so much in advance, i'm hanging here since days now without getting further...

Here is my code so far

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Moment from 'moment';
import { encode } from "base-64";
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient'
import { Badge, withBadge } from 'react-native-elements'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import { Alert, Button, RefreshControl, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View, ListView, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import styles from './../components/styles.js'
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';


export class SelectImage extends Component {
  SelectImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
         mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
         allowsEditing: true,
         aspect: [4, 3],
         quality: 1,
         exif: 1,
         base64: false
    });

    console.log("SelectImage", result.uri)

    //************
    // 1.)
    // Can i update the state from the other class maybe directly from here?!
    //
    //************
    return(result.uri)
  }
}

export default class ShowContent extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
          cover: false
    }
  }

  //************
  // 2.) 
  // This is the function that calls the class SelectImage and which i want to update the state.cover to
  // the image uri it gets from the response/result
  //
  //************
  SelectImage_func=()=>{
    var obj = new SelectImage();
    obj.SelectImage();
  }

  render() {
      const { navigation } = this.props;
      return (
        <View>
          <View>
            <LinearGradient style={styles.navBar} colors={['#444444', '#FFFFFF']}>
              <Text nativeID="foobar" style={{ color: "#444444", marginTop: 30 }}>
                Title
              </Text>
            </LinearGradient>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.page_header}>
              <Text>

                //************
                // 3.)
                // here should be the uri which i get from the class SelectImage respectively the
                // onPress event which calls the function SelectImage_func() some lines below
                //
                //************

                Add a Cover Image = {this.state.cover}
              </Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.take_or_select}>
              <View style={ styles.uploadPhoto }>
                <Text>
                  Upload a Photo
                </Text>

                //************
                // 4.)
                // onPress execute functions happens here in the upcoming line
                //
                //************

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.SelectImage_func()}>
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="file-image-outline" size={125}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new class for your ImagePicker, you can run the code in your component and keep the data in the state. I know this is not an answer to your question but below is the suggested way of achieving what you want to do.

```
class ShowContent extends Component {
  // ....
  state = {
    cover: null,
  }

  // create an async arrow function
  selectImage = async () => {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
         mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
         allowsEditing: true,
         aspect: [4, 3],
         quality: 1,
         exif: 1,
         base64: false
    });
        
    if (result.uri) {
        // update your state to rerender your component with the received image
        this.setState({cover: result.uri})
    }    
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <View>          
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.page_header}>
              <Text>
                Add a Cover Image = {this.state.cover}
              </Text> 

              // Or add an image and view it here. 
              <Image style={{width: 100, height: 100}} source={{ uri: this.state.cover }} />

            </View>

            <View style={styles.take_or_select}>
              <View style={ styles.uploadPhoto }>
                <Text>
                  Upload a Photo
                </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.selectImage()}>
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="file-image-outline" size={125}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
    )
  }
}
```

---

Secondly, here is a way to communicate between React components.
We create a function that updates the parent component's state and we pass it to the child component as a prop.

Whenever you call the function in the child component, it will rerender the parent component with the updated state.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
 state = {
  cover: null
 }

 parentFunction = (cover) => {
   // this cover is coming from child
   this.setState({cover: cover})
 }
 render() {
   return (
     <View>
       <ChildComponent cover={this.state.cover} updateParent={this.parentFunction} />
     </View>
   )
 }
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
 
 render() {
   // this cover is coming from parent
   console.log(this.props.cover)

   return (
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.props.updateParent("Some value")}>
         <Text>Call parent function</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   )
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @aytek your first post is working like a charm, you saved me a lot of time and hate speeches against my computer! ;-) Thanks!